# jQuery 1.7+ on(click..) doesn't work on <li> added dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a dialog with a

```
<ul id="suggestions0">
    <li id="suggestion0-0" class="suggestion">BLO</li>
    <li id="suggestion0-1" class="suggestion">BLU</li>
    <li id="suggestion0-2" class="suggestion">BLL</li>
    <li id="suggestion0-3" class="suggestion">BOO</li>
    <li id="suggestion0-4" class="suggestion">CLA</li>
</ul>
```

that I want to replace the content dynamically.

I change to ul content with this

```
        $("#suggestions0").html("<li id='test0-1' class='suggestion'>BLO</li><li id='test0-2' class='suggestion'>BLO</li><li id='test0-3' class='suggestion'>BLO</li><li id='test0-4' class='suggestion'>BLO</li><li id='test0-5' class='suggestion'>BLO</li><li id='test0-6' class='suggestion'>BLO</li>");
```

What I want is when I click on one of these word, I want to do something, suppose an alert.

I try to do this

```
$(".suggestion").on("click", function() {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

but the alert never appear.

here a sample that show the problem
http://jsfiddle.net/survivant/cyFxp/1/

in the sample, if you click on OK, it doesn't change to content, so if you click on a LI, it will works, but if you click on NOTOK, the events won't be received.

I'm using jQuery 1.7+, the live api is deprecated, or removed, it the APi suggest to use on().

Comment: `.on('click', ...` is the same as `.click(...`.

Comment: you have a js error on the fiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using `on` correctly. `live` is used to bind event handlers to the document to listen for events that bubble up from a specific selector, but by calling `on` explicitly on `.suggestion`, you will only attach the listeners to existing suggestions. So you need to use `on` to bind on an element that will always exist, and pass a selector to pick out the elements that get created dynamically.

```
// With live like this:
$('.suggestion').live('click', ...

// Is equivalent to this:
$(document).on('click', '.suggestion', ...

// Not this:
$('.suggestion').on('click', ...
```

In your case, rather than basing `on` off `document`, you can use your `ul`.

```
$("#suggestions0").on('click', '.suggestion', function(){
  alert(this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, not sure that is the best one, but seems to work.

```
$("#suggestions").on("click","li", function() {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The script below only bind click event to DOMs current exist in the page.

```
$(".suggestion").on("click", function() {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

To bind click event to all DOMs that are and will be created in the page. Bind the event to the `document` instead.

```
$(document).on("click", ".suggestion", function() {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

See [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/YpLmK/) for codes.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a selector to `on()` and it works like the old `live()`:

```
$("#suggestions0").on("click", ".suggestion", function () { alert(this.id); });
```

See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cyFxp/2/

Answer (score 0):

suggestions is not a class but an id thus
it should not be

```
$(".suggestion").on("click", function() {
alert(this.id);
});
```

But like this

```
$("#suggestion").on("click", function() {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

That is, instead of a dot you prefix it with a pound sign #.